# Hide node title on front page using template.php not css

Tags: theming, hooks

I'm building a drupal 7 bootstrap sub theme and want to hide the title of the nodes if there on the home page. I don't want to use css as its only hiding it I want to have the titles not render at all.

i have tried hook_preprocess_page() but didnt work:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if ($vars['is_front']) {
        $vars['title'] = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your close with `hook_preprocess_page()` but as you want to hide the node title (and not the page title) you need to use [`hook_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Going via `hook_preprocess_page()` this one worked for me:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if( drupal_is_front_page() ) drupal_set_title('');
}
```